# Count number of values in an array where not 0

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I'm trying to count the number of objects in the array where the the object key 'Value' is not 0.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'item[110189]',
    'value' => '0',
    'primary_key' => '110189',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'item[110190]',
    'value' => '50',
    'primary_key' => '110190',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'item[110191]',
    'value' => '0',
    'primary_key' => '110191',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'item[110192]',
    'value' => '0',
    'primary_key' => '110192',
  ),
)
```

I've tried the following:

```
$input_items = array_filter($request->items, function($item){

            $count = 0;

            foreach($item as $i){
                if(! $i['value'] == 0){
                    $count = $count + 1;
                }
            }

            return $count;
        }); // it will return an array

        return $input_items;
```

I get an error saying invalid object 'Value' which to be honest I half expected.

Comment: Can you update your question with the `var_export` version of the array?

Comment: `! $i['value'] == 0` to `$item['value'] != 0` and in the callback `$item['value']` no more loop needed, remove the foreach

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks - nice tip

Comment: Thanks @JustOnUnderMillions that seemed to work, I'll save that!

Comment: @Dev.Wol Check out my answer with the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed it this way:

```
$input_items = array_filter($arr, function ($item) {
    return ($item['value'] != 0);
});
```

**Full Code**

```
<?php
$arr = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'item[110189]',
    'value' => '0',
    'primary_key' => '110189',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'item[110190]',
    'value' => '50',
    'primary_key' => '110190',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'item[110191]',
    'value' => '0',
    'primary_key' => '110191',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'item[110192]',
    'value' => '0',
    'primary_key' => '110192',
  ),
);
$input_items = array_filter($arr, function ($item) {
    return ($item['value'] != 0);
});

print_r($input_items);
```

**Output** has only the non-zero entries:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => item[110190]
            [value] => 50
            [primary_key] => 110190
        )

)
```

**Demo: http://ideone.com/LUbMSb**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_reduce`:

```
print array_reduce($request->items, function($carry ,$item){
   if($item['value'] != 0){
      $carry++;
   }
   return $carry;
  },0);
```